# Changing control (that is in an array) from a timer: Not working

Tags: arrays, vb.net, controls

I'm trying to make a picture's visibility toggle on a timer. The picture I am trying to change is underscore(i). Here is that code:

```
Dim DigitSelected As Integer = 1
Public Underscores(3) As PictureBox
....
Private Sub CursorTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CursorTimer.Tick
    Me.Underscores(DigitSelected).Visible = Not (Me.Underscores(DigitSelected).Visible)
End Sub
```

This code above was previously working, but recently I moved where I was creating the pictureboxes and their stuff to a module on another page:

```
With Initials
For i As Byte = 1 To 3
    .Underscores(i) = New PictureBox
    With .Underscores(i)
        .Height = 60
        .Width = 144
        .ImageLocation = "Underscore.png"
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End With
    .Controls.Add(.Underscores(i))
Next
end with
```

Now when I use the top-most snippet of code, it throws no errors, and changes nothing. I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something small.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So you moved your code to a Module, then what does the dot in for example `.Underscores(i) = New PictureBox` refer to?

Comment: @VisualVincent Sorry, I've updated the code to include 'With Initials' and the 'end with'. The module is referencing the original form which is called Initials.

Comment: From my experience modules sometimes seem to not work as expected. I don't know the reason for it, but what happens if you change it to a class and mark all methods as `Shared`? That of course means that you would have to reference the class too, for example: `yourClass.DoYourStuff()`.

Comment: What kind of Timer is this ? A Windows.Form.Timer, a System.Timer or a System.Threading.Timer ? Are you running this with Option Strict On ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut it is a system.windows.forms.timer a.k.a the one you drag onto your form. I have no idea what Option Strict is, so likely the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve here, but here is what happens :

Everytime you run that loop, you **create three transparent PictureBox** that you add to your Main Form. You don't remove anything, nor hide anything !

If you want to toggle visibility, that is no way of doing so !

The best would be for you to know the PictureBoxes names, so you can do :

```
Dim pb1 = CType(Initials.FindControl("MyPictureBox", true), PictureBox)
If Not IsNothing(pb1) Then
    pb1.Visible = Not pb1.Visible
End If
```

Comment: Haha! You were right. I didn't think I was duplicating the controls, but then I realized I had put the code that created the controls in the area that was meant to set their locations (that normally gets updated and therefore called multiple times).

So I moved that chunk of code, created a single call to it instead and voila! Thanks a heap!